# Prevent HTML <dialog> from closing with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use Vue to programmatically prevent an HTML dialog element's close event from closing the dialog. Here's the code I'm working with:

```js
import {ref} from 'vue';
const dialogTemplateRef = ref();

//I want this toggle to prevent it from closing...
let preventClosing = true;

const closingHandler = function(event){
  //...but it has no effect
  if(preventClosing){
    event.preventDefault();
  } 
}
```

```html
<button @click="dialogTemplateRef.showModal()">open</button>
<dialog ref="dialogTemplateRef" @close="closingHandler">
  <button @click="dialogTemplateRef.close()">close</button>
</dialog>
```

Using `event.preventDefault()` fails to stop the dialog from closing. Using [Vue's event modifiers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling#event-modifiers) like `.stop` or `.prevent` also appears to have no effect. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that this isn't possible. It's not related to Vue, but rather the HTML dialog element's close event. It turns out that the close event ["is not cancelable and does not bubble."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/close_event)

Answer (score 1):

@launchoverit is right,You need to do it differently

```html
import {ref} from 'vue';
const dialogTemplateRef = ref();

//I want this toggle to prevent it from closing...
let preventClosing = true;

const closingHandler = function(){
  if(!preventClosing){
   dialogTemplateRef.value.close()
  } 
}

    <button @click="dialogTemplateRef.showModal()">open</button>
    <dialog ref="dialogTemplateRef" >
      <button @click="closingHandler">close</button>
    </dialog>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is helpful for implementing a dedicated close button, but in my case I wanted to interrupt the event itself to cover all of the possible ways to close the dialog (for instance, the user could still use the escape key in this case).